# Can a preposition be followed by a V-ed?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I was taught in school that a preposition is always followed by a noun, pronoun or Gerund. But recently, I have encountered a case (Ielts writing test) in which I had to describe and write something like this: “The household trash is delivered to the trucks before dumped at a landfill site”.

I don’t know if it is grammatically right because the trash is an object so it should be dumped by people while V-ed is not supposed to follow “before”, a preposition.

So could you help me out with this question, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This question might be better-served on our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/); according to traditional grammar, *before* is not a preposition here, but an adverb. Also note that most adjectives can be used metonymically or substantively as nouns (e.g. *the good, the bad, and the ugly* ), and so in turn you may find past participles as prepositional objects: *Upon the wicked He shall rain snares*.

Comment: @choster thank you so much for your response, so I can understand from your answer that the sentence “The household trash is delivered to the trucks before dumped at a landfill site” is grammatically correct, isn't it?

Comment: It's grammatically correct on an analytical basis but I find it inelegant. I would have rephrased it explicitly as *The household trash is delivered to the trucks before it is dumped at a landfill site* or *The household trash is delivered to the trucks, then dumped at a landfill site*. That is just my personal stylistic preference, however.

Comment: @choster million thanks from me, I got it now! wishing you all the best :)

Comment: @choster No, _before_ is not an adverb here in any grammar. I would consider the sentence utterly ungrammatical: there is a participle/gerund _being_ missing (“before being dumped…”), without which the sentence is just plain wrong to me, not merely inelegant. Adding in the missing word, _before_ is unambiguously a preposition. (If instead you make it a finite clause, “before it is dumped…”, _before_ would be considered a conjunction in traditional grammar, but still not an adverb. That would be uses like “Have you been here before?”.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *Being* is unnecessary because you have an *is* beforehand. *The household trash is delivered before [the household trash is] dumped*. Clumsy, painful even, but understandable.

Comment: @choster Definitely not to me. The verb cannot be partially elided in this way to me at all. Would you consider “He’d gone home before gone shopping” grammatical as well? A compound verbal construction like the perfect or the passive must be either repeated in full or reduced to a nominal form (i.e., a gerund) for it to be used after _before_ and similar prepositions.

Comment: thank you so much @JanusBahsJacquet. your answer is outstanding!

Comment: I agree with @choster. It's an elliptical sentence where the noun is simply not mentioned a second time before *dumped*. it's awkward but understandable. (You may not *like* or *recommend* some examples of ellipsis, but they can still be used.)

Comment: Alas, _ellipsis_ is not a technical term. It simply means 'something is missing', and doesn't say what's missing or what rule governs its deletion. One can't just delete any word at random, after all. I find the sentence ungrammatical, because _before_ does not take a past participle phrase as a complement. It does take a gerund phrase, so _being dumped_ is fine. _Being_, however, can't be deleted by conjunction reduction under identity with _is_ in _is delivered_, because it's _being_, not _is_. Conjunction reduction requires identity of form as well as lexeme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a valid English sentence.

I would say: "The household trash is delivered to the trucks before **being** dumped at a landfill site"